# VS Integration Services: flat file source to OLE DB destination - detect new data columns in file, add columns to table,import columns automatically?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

My place of work receives sets of pipe delimited files from many different clients that we use Visual Studio Integration Services projects to import into tables in our MS SQL 2008 R2 server for later processing - specifically with Data Flow Tasks containing Flat File Source to OLE DB Destination steps. Each data flow task has columns that are specifically mapped to columns in our tables, but the chances of a column addition in any file from any client are relatively high (and we are rarely warned that there will be changes), which is becoming tedious as I currently need to...

1. Run a python script that uses pyodbc to grab the columns contained in the destination tables and compare them to the source files to find out if there is a difference in columns
2. Execute the necessary SQL to add the columns to the destination tables
3. Open the corresponding VS Solution, refresh the columns in the flat file sources that have new columns and manually map each new column to the newly created columns in the OLE DB Destination

We are quickly getting more and more sites that I have to do this with, and I desperately need to find a way to automate this. The VS project can easily be automated if we could depend on the changes being accounted for, but as of now this needs to be a manual process to ensure we load all the data properly. Things I've thought about but have been unable to execute...

1. Using an XML parser - combined with the output of the python script mentioned above - to append new column mappings to the source/destination objects in the VS Package.dtsx.xml. I hit a dead end when I could not find out more information about creating a valid "DTS:DTSID" for new column mapping, and the file became corrupted whenever I edited it. This also seemed a very unstable option
2. Finding any built-in event handler in Visual Studio to throw an error if the flat file has a new, un-mapped column - I would be fine with this as a solution because we could confidently schedule the import projects to run automatically and only worry about changing the mapping for projects that failed. I could find a built in feature that does this. I'm also aware I could do this with a python script similar to the one mentioned above that fails if there are differences, but this would be extremely tedious to implement due to file-naming conventions and the fact that there are 50+ clients with more on the way.

I am open to any type of solution, even if it's just an idea. As this is my first question on Stack Overflow, I apologize if this was asked poorly and ask for feedback if the question could be improved. Thanks in advance to those that take the time to read!

Edit:
@Larnu stated that SSIS by default throws an error when unrecognized columns are found in the files. This however does not currently happen with our Visual Studio Integration Services projects and our team would certainly resist a conversion of all packages to SSIS at this point. It would be wonderful if someone could provide insight as to how to ensure the package would fail if there were new columns - in VS. If this isn't possible, I may have to pursue the difficult route as mentioned by @Dave Cullum, though I don't think I get paid enough for that!

Also, talking sense into the clients has proven to be impossible - the addition of columns will always be a crapshoot!

Comment: If you have defined the columns and a new one appears in it then, by default, SSIS will throw an error as the definition of the file has changed. As for making a data flow dynamic, I'm afraid you're out of luck. SSIS needs a data source and destination to be defined; it can't dynamically capture new columns, especially when those colum s don't exist in the destination. Personally, I would suggest speaking to whomever sends you the data and chat to then about the file structure and getting it more permanently defined. Data who's definition keeps changing isn't good data.

Comment: Larnu is right, SSIS doesn't support dynamic data flows (DTS could though!) . We encountered the same issue at our office, we import thousands of files per day, and our clients rarely tell us when things change...  I wound up writing a c# CLI which reads the files, parses the columns, builds a staging table to match file, then bulk inserts to SQL.  Our SSIS job loads up the import criteria such as schedules, ftp info, local paths, file types, encryption keys, etc, and does its work, calling the c# app to do the "data flow", the rest is in still handled via SSIS.

Comment: Addon: Once you get the file staged, you can write a stored proc which compares the schema of the staging table to the destination table, and adds new columns as required - the only caveat being it would be hard(er) to determine the proper data type since the staging table would likely be all (n)varchars.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback! I edited my question

Comment: I think you can redesign your package to notify you that a file has new columns. I would add a step to compare the count of |s+1 to Select Count(*) from informationschema.columns where tablename = [your destination table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a script task you can read your file and record how many pipes are in a line:

```
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
        {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                int ColumnCount = line.Length - line.Replace("|", "").Length +1;

        }
```

I assume you know how to set that to a variable.

Now add an execute SQL and store result as another variable:

```
Select Count(*) 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where TABLE_NAME = [your destination table]
```

Now exiting the execute SQL add a conditional arrow and compare the numbers. If they are equal continue your process. If they are not equal then go ahead and send an email (or some other type of notification.

Comment: I like this idea very much, and might decide to take it further by comparing the column name strings should Visual Studio be capable of that. I will need to grab the file paths from the dtsx xml file due to the varying naming conventions for each client. This is definitely a winner, thanks!

Comment: to put the column names into an array it is simply:  string[] cols = line.Split('|');